# Export to excel with multiple sheet using codeigniter?

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I have a table which contain employee details.I have to export these employee details in excel sheet.In excel each sheet contain each employee details and sheet name should be employee name. In models I have writen a query to fetch the details from database the following is the sample view code. This following code will give only one sheet of result How I implement multiple sheet excel

```
 <?PHP
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");    
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");    
    header ('Content-type: application/x-msexcel');
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee_workbook.xls" );  

    $this->load->view('reader/reader');

?>  
 <?PHP
    if($result->num_rows()>0)
    {
  ?>

  <?PHP foreach($result->result_array() as $entry):?>  
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Employee ID</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Employee Name</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Check in Time</strong></td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Project Name</strong></td>        
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Check Out Time</strong></td>   
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $entry['emp_id']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?PHP echo $entry['emp_name']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?PHP echo $entry['in_time']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?PHP echo $entry['prj_name']; ?></td>
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?PHP echo $entry['out_time']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?PHP endforeach;?>
<?PHP
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), I have tried almost every script out there to export data to excel, nothing does it better than PHPExcel, you can even export to multiple sheets.

Comment: I got confused using phpExcel

Comment: yes at first i got confused as well but as you read more documentation you will get familiar with it. look http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework and http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework

Comment: here is another example of codeigniter and phpexcel https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPExcel

Comment: An Error Was Encountered

Non-existent class: IOFactory

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$excel when i implenting the other one this error is comming

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com). Download the [Excel library for PHP](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library).
You can find a lot a code samples starting from [here](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/getting-started/easyxls-com-excel-component.html). You can save multiple sheets using this library.